# PhpMailer, ler email em php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Boa tarde ! dei uma procurada da internet e não achei muito sobre, não sei se com phpmailer ou outra ferramenta que seja melhor, teria alguma maneira de eu ficar monitorando os emails que recebo no gmail por exemplo, e dependendo se recebesse um email com o assunto X acontecesse uma inserção de dados no meu sistema?

obrigada, desde já.

Comment: Use [imap](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.remote.mail.php).

Comment: Em uma brevíssima pesquisa encontrei vários artigos sobre o tema.. :)
Segue um deles: https://phppot.com/php/gmail-email-inbox-using-php-with-imap/